# Can someone explain the cause of error in the os.wait()?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, fork

I have this piece of code for `fork` child process respectively in a top down with `wait()` function but when i ran the script i got an error.

```
import os

reply = int(input("Enter no of proc:   "))
pid = os.fork()

for i in range(reply):

    if pid == 0:
        pid = os.fork()

    else:
        os.wait()

        print(i,os.getpid(), os.getppid())
```

the output for 3 is:

```
Enter no of proc:   3
2 44070 44069
1 44069 44068
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/saman/PycharmProjects/Syslab/test.py", line 12, in <module>
    os.wait()
ChildProcessError: [Errno 10] No child processes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/saman/PycharmProjects/Syslab/test.py", line 12, in <module>
    os.wait()
ChildProcessError: [Errno 10] No child processes
0 44068 20928
```

I don't understand the error!

Comment: move `print(i,os.getpid(), os.getppid())` _before_ `os.wait()` to understand what's happening. BTW cannot help you further since I'm running windows: `fork` isn't available there.

Comment: i got the same same error : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/saman/PycharmProjects/Syslab/test.py", line 13, in <module>
    os.wait()
ChildProcessError: [Errno 10] No child processes`

Comment: of course, but you get the "print" statement before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are executing `os.wait()` in children. These children has no process to wait on.

I think you want to do something like this:

```
import os

reply = int(input("Enter no of proc:   "))
pid = os.fork()

for i in range(reply):

    if pid == 0:
        pid = os.fork()

if pid != 0:
    os.wait()
    print(os.getpid(), os.getppid())
```

Comment: that should fix it, yes. Bug is probably because `pid` was overwritten by a valid non-zero in the loop.